# Displaying a paper-toast polymer element in dart

Tags: dart, polymer, paper-elements

Does anyone know how to show a paper-toast polymer element from dart. The only examples I can find use 
`<paper-button raised onclick="document.querySelector('#toast1').show()">Discard Draft</paper-button>`

I have tried using `$['myToast'].show()` in my dart code but it doesn't seem to work. I have also tried using the querySelector and calling show() but I get a warning that show is not a method. If there isn't a way to do this from dart is there a way to call the javascript that will show the toast from dart?

Comment: Can you please provide more code? How does your HTML look like? Where is your code placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick for me...

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_toast.dart';

document.querySelector('#notification').show();
```

Ignore the warning... its just that... a warning.

I suggest you clone the example project and take a look:
https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-core-and-paper-examples